# Array Correlation Between 3 Different Loops using Bash

Tags: bash

I have 3 loops that I use to determine the permission level of AWS user accounts.

This array lists the AWS policy Effect:

```
  for ((policy_index=0;policy_index<${#aws_managed_policies[@]};++policy_index)); do
  aws_policy_arn="${aws_managed_policies[policy_index]}"
  aws_policy_version_id=$(aws iam get-policy --policy-arn "$aws_policy_arn" --profile="$aws_key" | jq -r '.Policy.DefaultVersionId')
  readarray -t aws_policy_effects < <( if aws iam get-policy-version --policy-arn "$aws_policy_arn" --version-id "$aws_policy_version_id" --profile="$aws_key" 2> /dev/null | jq -r '.PolicyVersion.Document.Statement[].Effect' 2> /dev/null
  then
    true
  else
    aws iam get-policy-version --policy-arn "$aws_policy_arn" --version-id "$aws_policy_version_id" --profile="$aws_key" 2> /dev/null | jq -r '.PolicyVersion.Document.Statement.Effect' 2> /dev/null
  fi )
done
```

I get the effect of the policy with this loop (Allow/Deny):

```
for ((effect_index=0;effect_index<${#aws_policy_effects[@]};++effect_index)); do
    policy_effect="${aws_policy_effects[effect_index]}"
    if [[ "$policy_effect" = "Allow" ]]; then
        aws_policy_effects[effect_index]='ALLOW'
        unset aws_policy_effects
    elif [[ "$policy_effect" = "Deny" ]]; then
        aws_policy_effects[effect_index]='DENY'
    fi 
done
```

And I get the list of services that the user has permission to with this loop:

```
readarray -t aws_policy_actions < <(aws iam get-policy-version --policy-arn "$aws_policy_arn" --version-id "$aws_policy_version_id" --profile="$aws_key" 2> /dev/null | jq -r '.PolicyVersion.Document.Statement[].Action' 2> /dev/null  | grep '*')

if [[ "$aws_policy_effect" = "Allow" ]]; then
    for ((action_index=0;action_index<${#aws_policy_actions[@]};++action_index)); do
        policy_action="${aws_policy_actions[action_index]}"
        if [[ "$policy_action" = "^*$" ]]; then
            admin_access="YES"
        elif [[ -n "$policy_action" ]]; then
            policy_action=$(echo "$policy_action" | cut -d: -f1)
            admin_access="YES"
            aws_admin_services+=("$policy_action")
        else
            admin_access="NO"              
        fi         
    done   # action loop
fi
```

I want the 3 loops to correspond.

I need the ARN, Effect and Policies loops to agree: ARN1 with Effect 1 and Policy 1, ARN 2 with effect 2 and Policy 2, and so on.

How can I best achieve this? Do I need to embed the 3 loops within one another in order to achieve this?

Comment: Can't you use the index? Instead of `aws_policy_effects+=("ALLOW")`, you'd use `aws_policy_effects[effect_index]='ALLOW'`.

Comment: Also, you use `aws_policy_effect="Deny"`, which defaults to setting the first element instead of appending one.

Comment: Yes, good point. Thank you!

Comment: Corrected that in the OP.

Comment: That's a lot of complexity per line. While it might work like a champ, I'd suggest breaking it into smaller bites, even if that means adding otherwise superfluous variables to store the intermediate results. In ten months when someone else has taken over maintaining this and something upstream changes that breaks it, they are going to have to do something similar anyway to read through it. Readability is a resource - manage it. ...also, I prefer `testCmd || nextCmd` to `if testCmd; then true; else nextCmd; fi`. YMMV.

Comment: Yeah that is really good advice. I will try to achieve that. But no one has answered my question. Do the 3 elements correspond with one another the way it's written? Or do I need to nest the 3 loops inside one another to do that? Thanks!